# how to check if excel worksheet has merged cells using c#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I want to check if excel worksheet using `c#` has merged cells I searched and found many ways that talking about how to merge or Unmerged cell or check if there is cell within fix range of sheet like `[a1:100]` what I actually want is to

check if there is any merged cells in all sheets and all cells within all excel file or at least the sheet I am working

thanks for help in advanced

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in using the following method

```vb
Function CountMerged(pWorkRng As Range) As Long
'Updateby20140307
Dim rng As Range
Dim total As Long
Set dt = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each rng In pWorkRng
    If rng.MergeCells Then
        TempAddress = rng.MergeArea.Address
        dt(TempAddress) = ""
    End If
Next
CountMerged = dt.Count
End Function
```

Source: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1501-excel-count-merged-cells.html

Hope that this will help you

Comment: Interesting idea on using a dictionary for this. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach will be of help and it's in c#:

```
using Spire.Xls;

namespace Detect_Merged_Cells
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
            workbook.LoadFromFile("Sample.xlsx");
            Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

            CellRange[] range = sheet.MergedCells;
            foreach (CellRange cell in range)
            {
                cell.UnMerge();
            }
            workbook.SaveToFile("Output.xlsx",ExcelVersion.Version2010);
        }
    }
}
```

The above solution is based on a 3rd party library - Spire.XLS (you can get it from nuget and note I work for Spire). For more information, check this link:
https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Cells/How-to-detect-merged-cells-in-a-worksheet.html